# Typescript: call a method by this + its name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am converting a project to Typsescript. It's a rough ride, but I am getting there step by step. One thing keeps eluding me, though.

I can do this in **plain Javascript**:

```
class Example {
  callThis(methodName) {
    if (typeof this[methodName] === "function"){
      this[methodName]();
    }
  }

  getSomeText() {
    return this.someText;
  }

  setSomeText(someText) {
    this.someText = someText;
  }

  myMethod() {
    console.log(this.getSomeText());
  }

  myOtherMethod() {
    //etc
  }

  //and more methods that can be called with callThis()
}

const aTest = new Example;
aTest.setSomeText("calling myMethod()");
aTest.callThis("myMethod");
```

This runs fine and outputs "calling myMethod()". When I convert this to Typescript, I get an error on the `callThis` method. It tells me:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Example'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Example'.

How can I coax TypeScript to accept this setup? I will add new callable methods later on, it's not just this one, so I would like to be as flexible as possible. I already created a few new types, but I am still an infant at this stage, so bear with me.

The whole idea behind this is that the class is used to create a dialog from an HTML `<template>` node, and the `callThis` function is used to add an event listener to it after the node is added to the DOM.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why don't you just call the method you want in the first place?

Comment: This strikes me as an X-Y problem and/or architecture issue. A completely arbitrary setup like this would almost *have* to be sprinkled with `any`, which defeats the purpose. My first approach would have been to supply a context to functions in a name => impl structure, allowing simple typing of both the context and functions.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković You are right, I have been the victim of tunnel vision. I wanted to let one function do all the rendering, and then call the function, but that is unnecessary and pollutes the render bit. Thanks!

ps. Noobish here: should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this this answer is useful but I had a class something like this

```
class MakeViews {
  offset = 0;

  constructor(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer) {
    this.arrayBuffer = arrayBuffer;
  }
  getView<TypedArrayConstructor>(Ctor: TypedArrayConstructor, size: number) {
     const view = new TypedArrayConstructor(this.arrayBuffer, this.offset, size);
     this.offset += view.byteLength;
     return view;
  }
  i8(size: number) { return getView(Int8Array, size); }
  u8(size: number) { return getView(Uint8Array, size); }
  i16(size: number) { return getView(Int16Array, size); }
  u16(size: number) { return getView(Uint16Array, size); }
  i32(size: number) { return getView(Int32Array, size); }
  u32(size: number) { return getView(Uint32Array, size); }
  f32(size: number) { return getView(Float32Array, size); }
  f64(size: number) { return getView(Float64Array, size); }
  ....
}
```

and I had code that called it based on some structure definition

```
const structDef = {
   color: { type: 'u8', size: 4, },
   foo: { type: 'i8', size: 1, },
};

const views = {};
const m = new MakeViews(5);
for (const [key, {type, size}] of structDef) {
   views[key] = m[type](size);  // <---- Typescript doesn't like this
}
```

I understood that it's not strictly "type correct" but it works. Anyway, I tried a bunch of more type friendly ways. I was surprised to find that various ways of being more type correct all had [similar performance](https://jsbenchit.org/?src=ddc192654e610293525c847b1a42e39f).

Below are my nonsense examples. Sorry for the poor naming.

Of course each browser has its own strengths. And further, which method wins can depend on how many times the functions are called per class, at least for these tests. For example, Chrome 107, if the functions are called a 1000 times per class instance then arrow functions by name wins. If the functions are called 16 times per class than the original, non-typescript friendly method wins but the 2nd method, an object of named functions, is not that much slower, ~10% and of course if the functions did more than just an add and a multiply that 10% would be even lower. It makes some sense that for smaller usages the non arrow function solution becomes slower as it has to make new closures for every class instance but it wasn't so bad that I'd worry about it.

Also, I tested in JavaScript, not typescript. I don't know what if any overhead typescript's translation might add.

```
class ByClass {
  #count = 0;
  by2(v: number) {
    this.#count += v * 2;
  }
  by4(v: number) {
    this.#count += v * 4;
  }
  by8(v: number) {
    this.#count += v * 8;
  }
  by16(v: number) {
    this.#count += v * 16;
  }
  add(name: string, v: number) {
    this[name](v);   // <-- problematic (not type safe)
  }
  getResult() {
      return this.#count;
  }
}

class ByClassFn {
  count = 0;
  fns = {
    by2(v: number) { this.count += v * 2 },
    by4(v: number) { this.count += v * 4 },
    by8(v: number) { this.count += v * 8 },
    by16(v: number) { this.count += v * 16 },
  };
  add(name: string, v: number) {
    this.fns[name].call(this, v);
  }
  getResult() {
    return this.count;
  }
}

class ByClassArrowFn {
  count = 0;
  fns = {
    by2: (v: number) => { this.count += v * 2 },
    by4: (v: number) => { this.count += v * 4 },
    by8: (v: number) => { this.count += v * 8 },
    by16: (v: number) => { this.count += v * 16 },
  };
  add(name: string, v: number) {
    this.fns[name](v);
  }
  getResult() {
    return this.count;
  }
}

class ByClassStaticFn {
  count = 0;
  static fns = {
    by2(v: number) { this.count += v * 2 },
    by4(v: number) { this.count += v * 4 },
    by8(v: number) { this.count += v * 8 },
    by16(v: number) { this.count += v * 16 },
  };

  add(name: string, v: number) {
    ByClassStaticFn.fns[name].call(this, v);
  }
  getResult() {
    return this.count;
  }
}

class ByClassStaticMapFn {
  count = 0;
  static fns = new Map<string, (n: number) => void>([
    [ 'by2', function(v: number) { this.count += v * 2 }, ],
    [ 'by4', function(v: number) { this.count += v * 4 }, ],
    [ 'by8', function(v: number) { this.count += v * 8 }, ],
    [ 'by16', function(v: number) { this.count += v * 16 }, ],
  ]);

  add(name: string, v: number) {
    ByClassStaticMapFn.fns.get(name)!.call(this, v);
  }
  getResult() {
    return this.count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to rewrite the code that calls this class, thus avoiding dynamically called methods.
My take away after trying the code that was suggested as an answer: don't try to call methods dynamically in TypeScript, there isn't a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

In order to convert it to typescript you need write custom typeguards:

```js
const withoutParams = (fn: (...args: any) => any): fn is () => void =>
    fn.length === 0

const isFunction = (fn: any): fn is () => void =>
    typeof fn === 'function'

class Example {
    someText?: string;

    callThis<T,>(this: T, methodName: keyof T) {
        const x = this[methodName]
        if (isFunction(x) && withoutParams(x)) {
            x();
        }
    }

    getSomeText() {
        return this.someText;
    }

    setSomeText(someText: string) {
        this.someText = someText;
    }

    myMethod() {
        console.log(this.getSomeText());
    }

    myOtherMethod() {
    }

}

const aTest = new Example;
aTest.setSomeText("calling myMethod()");
aTest.callThis("myMethod");
```

If you want to call `this[methodName]`, first of all you need to assure TS that it is a function. Then you need to assure TS that this function is without arguments.

Also, you need to tell TS that you might have `someText` property

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gSygCxAVygBQIYCdsC2EMAvDABQBmYAXBQHSN4DmEd2YAngJSkB8MDjzrUYCYuV4kBANxAIAJvwBQMNTGr0ANgFMwzFKRJkADMuWhIscQDE0YYFAThSFauy7cRYMRKmz5JWlVdShOAAcdEEoNH2MyAHJKe0dnMATzYC1sCGIAUQAPQnDdGABvELUIEAIdABUdAqgAfjpoXAR9AG5zdRhgbC0tOuRxAB46vnIUcTo6gBoYWpQQBQA5Qh06AGsdTmiYOt4Kvr7LaBgC1xmIAG1l1HXNgF1K04QY8lsUp3ByAt4ADJAfAkKgMDh8ER-txjm9TuoCpIegi1ABfN4Yt7MHRQADKNXqjSgknK8PUuFxaFwPhu9GqtQaTRR6ixfQguIJjOJ5AZRKabSgHX0cNRMDpfKZsDIkuJLPRvXUBE4AFlcY9SSdUecQLptCBmNNRhB6Dj8YSpZJuPKYGylZwAPIoHS4NUrBSazHmLHnWDYBoXMhgHRwGCFYq6Hr+nTQemci08gBEAyGnWYS1V6tWkkT1uU0djKeGxvIieVbseua6QA)

Comment: Won't really work. `x` function will be called with the wrong `this` scope and it will throw.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković is right, this is not defined when you call getSomeText.

Comment: You can infer `this` just like I did in `callThis`

Answer (score -1):

Something like this works for me. I am not sure how you are going to pass the parameters...

```
export class Example {
  private my_text = '';
  callThis(member: keyof Example): void {
    this[member](member);
  }
  getSomeText(): void {
    this.my_text = 'getSomeText';
  }

  setSomeText(): void {
    this.my_text = 'setSomeText';
  }
}
```

and then in index.ts

```
import { Example } from './Example';

const lo_example = new Example();
lo_example.callThis('getSomeText');
```

Comment: This would call `lo_example.getSomeText('getSomeText')`... not sure that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: the way I understoor it, he wanted to call methods dynamically. He gets it.